# I have a problem with the dark mode button on my webpage. Whatever i do, it always bugs as if it was a infinity loop

Tags: javascript

```
  var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var i = paragraphs.length;
    function toggleDarkMode(){
      while(i> 0){
        paragraphs[i-1].classList.toggle("dark-mode-p");

        i-1;
      }
    }
```

I tried to put the variables inside the function, didn't help either :(

Then I decided to use the for loop:

```
function toggleDarkMode(){
  var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  for(var i = paragraphs.length; i >= 0; i--){

    paragraphs[i-1]classList.toggle("dark-mode-p");

  }
}
```

Ps. sorry for my English, I know it sucks XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is simply adding/removing a class from the BODY only.

Then on any div that you want to change the color of call it something like: mode-change-p and only modify that class when body is in dark mode. This will allow you to easily change other elements also without changing the javascript.

```js
var _btn = document.getElementById("btn-changemode");

_btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
   var body = document.body;
   body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
});
```

```css
body.dark-mode{
background:black;
}

.dark-mode .mode-change-p{
color:white;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-changemode" type="button">Change</button>

<P class="mode-change-p">DOES CHANGE</p>
<P>DOESN'T CHANGE</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you are trying to decrement with `i-1;`, which just resolves to what that value would be.  It doesn't actually change the `i`.

However, you can just iterate the actual array using a `for ... of`, you don't need the index.

```js
function toggleMode() {
  for (const p of Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("p"))) {
    p.classList.toggle("dark-mode-p");
  }
}

document.getElementById("mode-shift").addEventListener("click", () => {
  toggleMode()

})
```

```css
p.dark-mode-p {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</main>
<button id="mode-shift">Mode shift</button>
```